# How to query to fetch last 5 months records?

Tags: django

I have a model named 'DemoModel' it has a field called demo_date.

I want to fetch the last 5 months i.e;(from current month records to past 5 months records) records by querying on the **demo_date** field.

My models look like

```
class DemoModel(models.Model):
     demo_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

Comment: post your attempts..

Comment: @praveen jb did you check my answer

Comment: no, i am trying as @rob suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
```

to calculate the five_months_ago parameter accurately.

And then get the objects like this:

```
target_set = DemoModel.objects.filter(demo_date__gte=five_months_ago)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

today = datetime.today()
long_ago = today + timedelta(days=-150)

retrieved_data = DemoModel.objects.filter(demo_date__gte=long_ago)
```

Comment: datetime.date.today() should be the right way nowadays

Answer (score 0):

This function give subscription or add months

```
def monthdelta(date, delta):
    m, y = (date.month+delta) % 12, date.year + ((date.month)+delta-1) // 12
    if not m: m = 12
    d = min(date.day, [31,
        29 if y%4==0 and not y%400==0 else 28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31][m-1])
    return date.replace(day=d,month=m, year=y)
```

query goes here

```
from datetime import datetime
query= DemoModel.objects.filter(demo_date__gte=monthdelta(datetime.now(), -5)
)
```